# How can I get my hedgehog into space in 7 days?

Tags: hedgehog-launch

Hedgehog Launch (for iOS) has an achievement called *Incredible Launch* which you can get if you launch your hedgehog into space in 7 days or less. I'm looking for some pointers on how to get the achievement, what's the best way to spend money earned, etc.

Pointers for doing the same thing in the [Flash version](http://armorgames.com/play/1760/hedgehog-launch) would likely also be fine as they play pretty much the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to the iOS version, but assuming it's similar enough to the flash version:

The most important upgrades for getting to space is the launcher height and band elasticity. Fully maxing out the e-rocket is worth (roughly) 3 points in the above upgrades. (When both are at 10; a simple launch straight up will go all the way into space with no further input required.)

The chute, radar and jet pack upgrades are mostly useful for getting the money required to upgrade the launcher; but they still require some luck for effective use.

The launcher and band is also very helpful in getting the cash for further upgrades, as they'll give more altitude and hang-time when upgraded, yielding higher multipliers.

Answer (score 3):

This video shows how to do it in 7 days:

Comment: This video merely shows someone doing it in 7 days, not *how*.

Comment: @fredley It shows which upgrades were bought and the order that they were bought.

Answer (score 0):

It's total luck. There's no strategy. As long as you buy only the bands and launcher, you should be good. I got to space in 6 days by just buying those 2 things.

Comment: This answer provides nothing that has not already been said.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's total luck.  I found a parachute useful for getting points--you stay in the air longer which increases the multiplier.  Luck plays a major factor, though--my best jump netted over $30k, most of it while I was out of fuel, rockets and parachutes and so it was purely chance.